# Change color of Bootstrap 4 navbar on hover link

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to know how to change the color when hovering over a link

Thanks for any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a class="underline" href="welcome.html">./home </a>
  <a class="underline" href="about.html">./about </a>
  <a class="underline" href="projects.html">./projects </a>
  <a class="underline" href="ctf.html">./ctf's</a>
</nav>
```

I did solve it by:

```
a[href] {
  color: #ffff; /* Change this to which color you prefer */
}
```

In the css

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add some css:

```html
<style>
.underline:hover {
  color: red; /* text color */
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your own css file to overwrite bootstrap ->
`nav a :hover{ color: #yourcolor; }`

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
    .underline:hover {
      color: red !important;  /* for link text color */
      text-decoration: none; /* for delete under line */
    }
</style>
```